# When table joins query order scrambles

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let me explain my query. It sums the best 5 scores of each player and makes than a ranking of these scores. The first query works, but when I add a player-table to add the full names of the players it scrambles the sum and the totals per players are not correct.

This query gives the good total scores per player:

```
SET @score_rank := 0; 
SET @current_player  = '';
SET @topN = 5;
Select ATLEET_ID as ID, SUM(SCORE) as SUMSUM
   From (Select r.ATLEET_ID, r.SCORE, k.SEASON, k.TYPE, 
    @score_rank := IF(@current_player = r.ATLEET_ID, (@score_rank + 1), 1) AS score_rank,
    @current_player := r.ATLEET_ID
  From RESULTATEN r LEFT JOIN KALENDER k ON ( r.KALENDER_ID = k.KALENDER_ID )
  Where  k.TYPE = 'Cup'  AND k.SEASON = '2016-2017' 
  Order By r.ATLEET_ID, r.SCORE DESC) sorted 
Where score_rank <= @topN 
Group By ID;
```

But this one gives the wrong total per player: (joined the PLAYERS table)

```
SET @score_rank := 0; 
SET @current_player  = '';
SET @topN = 5;
Select ATLEET_ID as ID, SUM(SCORE) as SUMSUM
   From (Select r.ATLEET_ID, r.SCORE, k.SEASON, k.TYPE, 
    @score_rank := IF(@current_player = r.ATLEET_ID, (@score_rank + 1), 1) AS score_rank,
    @current_player := r.ATLEET_ID
  From RESULTATEN r LEFT JOIN KALENDER k ON ( r.KALENDER_ID = k.KALENDER_ID ) JOIN PLAYERS s ON (r.ATLEET_ID = s.PLAYER_ID)   
  Where  k.TYPE = 'Cup'  AND k.SEASON = '2016-2017' 
  Order By r.ATLEET_ID, r.SCORE DESC) sorted 
Where score_rank <= @topN 
Group By ID;
```

I don't understand what is causing the miscalculation or why this is happening.

Comment: If you want the results in a particular order, you need to include an `ORDER BY` in the outermost `SELECT`.  Period.

Comment: Your LEFT JOINs execute as regular INNER JOINs... Move right side table conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result!

Answer (score 0):

With the help found in the comments I figured out a query that works for me:

```
SET @score_rank := 0;
SET @current_player  = '';
SET @topN = 5;
Select ATLEET_ID as ID, SUM(SCORE) as SUMSUM
From (Select r.ATLEET_ID, r.SCORE, k.SEASON, k.TYPE, @score_rank := IF(@current_player = r.ATLEET_ID, (@score_rank + 1), 1) AS score_rank, @current_player := r.ATLEET_ID
    From RESULTATEN r 
    Inner join KALENDER k on (r.KALENDER_ID = k.KALENDER_ID ) and SEIZOEN = '2016-2017' and WEDSTRIJDTYPE = 'Dutch Cup snowboard' 
    Order By r.ATLEET_ID, r.SCORE DESC) sorted 
Left join PLAYERS on (sorted.ATLEET_ID = s.PLAYER_ID)
Where score_rank <= @topN 
Group by ID;
ORDER BY SUMSUM DESC LIMIT 0, 2000;
```

I moved the join with the PLAYERS table from the inner Select to the outer Select. And I moved the right side table conditions from the WHERE to the ON.